# Using an Up-Down control for WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am looking for an Up-Down control for the Windows Phone, and I know there is one in the Silverlight 4 toolkit but how do I reference it for use in my Phone project? I tried referencing the controls.dll and the controls.input dll but no luck.
If there is a free control you recommend for up-down, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Windows phone specific version of the Toolkit [here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034).  However it does not contain an implementation of an up down control and in my opinion that's a good thing.  Not all UI idioms we are used to in mouse driven applications are good for direct touch devices.  You'll note there are no scroll bars with up down buttons on them in WP7.

An entirely new gesture based idiom for quickly selecting numbers might be needed.  Possibly mulitple methods could be employed each suited to different scenarios where the domain of values is small, medium or large and where the numbers are just integers or include decimal fractions.

Comment: I appreciate your recommendation and I will look into it. I initially thought that the LoopingSelector is not a good design solution in my case. I'd like to provide the user with the ability to type in or use buttons to +/- the value. I want to show it for items in a list and databinding might be an issue. Let's see.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what Anthony has said; in addition, presumably you have a fixed range of values that you want the user to be able to select from, in whihc case I'd reccomend using the LoopingSelector from the Silverlight Toolkit for WP7, as described in [Nigel Sampson's blog post](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/using-loopingselector-from-the-silverlight-toolkit).

Comment: I'd also recommend looping selector for this purpose. Another useful link for reference http://babaandthepigman.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/wp7-looping-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a Numeric Up Down control for Windows Phone 7 that you need. Check here - http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx

Comment: Ops - sorry didn't really noticed that. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any free alternative. It should be relatively easy to implement one on your own - let me know if I can help you.